# change ref of branchB when parent branchA was changed from master

Tags: git, rebase

There must be a similar question already asked about this topic but I could not find it nor the right words to look for it.

Let's say I have this:

```
a -- b                  <-- Master
      \
       d -- e           <-- Branch1
             \
              f -- g    <-- Branch2
```

But at some point, before merging to Master I had to rewrite the code done in commits `d` and `e` of `Branch1`, so they become `d'` and `e'`:

```
a -- b                  <-- Master
     |\
     | d'--e'           <-- Branch1
      \
       d --e
            \
             f -- g    < -- Branch2
```

How do I tell my `Branch2` that `f`'s parent commit should be `e'` and not the old `e`?

```
a -- b                  <-- Master
      \
       d'-- e'          <-- Branch1
             \
              f -- g    <-- Branch2
```

Basically, when `Branch1` Pull Request will be merged on `master` via Github, `Branch2` won't contain `d`, `e`, `d'` nor `e'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact command would be:

```
git rebase --onto Branch1 e Branch2
```

You would replay all commits of `Branch2` from *after* the old `Branch1` base (`e`) onto the new `Branch1` HEAD.

All you need to do, when rewriting `Branch1` is to *first* make a marker (a `tmp` branch or a tag) in order to mark the '`e`' commit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand your second point about _making a marker_ on `Branch1`. Can you try to explain it further or use an example?

Comment: I found a different way, (on `branch2`) `git rebase -i branch1`, drop the old commit references `d` and `e` then `git rebase --continue` so that `d` and `e` become `d'` and `e'`. I had to resolve few conflicts though. Do you think it is a good approach too?

Comment: @MrYoshiji VonC is saying that you need some way to identify the commit which you call `e` here. You can use the SHA1 hash if you wish. The "marker" he refers to is more likely a temporary branch or a tag so that you can more easily find the commit.

Comment: @MrYoshiji For a branch with only a few commits, your solution is reasonable. If there are a lot of commits between the original Branch1 and Branch2, then manually dropping each one can be time consuming.

Comment: Oh I see! I understand that the `e` in the `rebase --onto` is referring to `e`'s SHA1, thank you @Code-Apprentice :)

Comment: @MrYoshiji You cannot rebase branch1 alone: that would replay d and e as well. e is referring to e, not e'

Comment: @VonC in the interactive rebase of branch2 with branch1 I dropped the old references to commits `e` and `d`, so that afterwards branch2's commits were put after branch1's commits `e'` and `d'`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I understand, but this is error-prone: a rebase --onto is not.

Comment: I agree with you, I tried both and still get the same result but --onto is less error prone

Answer (score 2):

(tl;dr: what you're after is actually Git's default behavior. Just tell it about upstream relationships for your branches and your command is plain `git rebase`.)

That's how Git behaves when you've told it about upstream relationships and let it use them, as is its default.

Try this:

```
new() { touch $1; git add .; git commit -m$1; }
git init forktest; cd $_
new a
new b
git checkout -b Branch1
new d 
new e
git checkout -b Branch2
new f
new g
```

and you've got your initial conditions, now do your complete rewrite on Branch1:

```
git checkout -B Branch1 master
new d\'
new e\'
git checkout Branch2
```

to get

```
[jthill@gadabout forktest]$ lgdo
* 6a5240f (Branch1) e'
* 4487d2d d'
| * 53e5c85 (HEAD -> Branch2) g
| * e9e416b f
| * 157a7a3 e
| * 266e1d7 d
|/  
* 4b78ef0 (master) b
* 93871d3 a
```

exactly your picture, as `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` draws it.  Now I, like you, realize I need my current branch's rebase to follow along with the changes to Branch1, so I tell Git about the relationship:

```
[jthill@gadabout forktest]$ git branch -u Branch1
Branch 'Branch2' set up to track local branch 'Branch1'.
```

and ask Git for a plain-vanilla rebase:

```
[jthill@gadabout forktest]$ git rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: f
Applying: g
[jthill@gadabout forktest]$
```

Git has found Branch2's upstream, hunted through its reflogs, discovered commit `e` is the most-recent historical merge base and used that as the rebase cutoff.

If you specify the new base explicitly, Git won't do this hunting by default, but you can ask for it explicitly with the `--fork-point` option.

Comment: I am not entirely clear on the reflog-fork-point part, but that looks neat! +1

Comment: Branch1's the upstream, it looks through Branch1's reflogs and finds that a little while ago the merge base between Branch1 and Branch2 was `e`.  So that's where Branch2 and its upstream Branch1 once forked, and should be the cut point when Branch2 gets rebased onto where its upstream Branch1 is now.

Comment: Yes, I understand all the terms. I forgot about the "If `<upstream>` is not specified, the upstream configured in `branch.<name>`.remote and `branch.<name>.merge` options will be used " part of the doc, combined with the `--fork-point` option. Nice!